# How to get access and customize Freemarker's Configuration object in spring-boot 2.x?

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

How to get access and customize Freemarker's Configuration object in spring-boot 2.x?

It allows to set square bracket syntax as default option with something like:

`Configuration#setTagSyntax(Configuration.SQUARE_BRACKET_TAG_SYNTAX)`

which is not possible with any of spring.freemarker.* configuration property.

Also, it should be possible to introduce default imports having access to direct configuration of this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to set any FreeMarker configuration settings with `spring.freemarker.settings.<settingName>`, like `spring.freemarker.settings.tagSyntax = square_bracket`. See the JavaDoc of `Configuration.setSetting(String, String)` for more (https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/core/Configurable.html#setSetting-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). This is the method to which Spring delegates the assignments under `spring.freemarker.settings`; Spring itself doesn't know what "settings" exist or how to parse them.

Comment: Tested with spring.freemarker.settings.tagSyntax = square_bracket and spring.freemarker.settings.auto_import = <some import declaration>. Works perfectly.